# RDP Multiple Monitor limit Resolution

Tags: rdp

At home have a dual-monitor setup with one 13" monitor with 3200x1800 res, and one 20" monitor with 1920x1080. At work my setup is two 20" 1920x1080 monitors. I'd like to RDP from home using both monitors, but limit the resolution on the smaller monitor to 1920x1080 (everything renders so tiny at the full 3200x1800 that it's almost unusable), but the main settings only allow multiple monitor RDP at full resolution. I'm wondering if there are any advanced settings on either the client or server side that can set a limit on the highest resolution allowed over RDP, so I can see what I'm doing on the smaller, higher res monitor.

Oh, my home machine is running Windows 10 and my work machine is running Windows Server 2008 R2, in case that makes a difference.

Answer (score 0):

I found the setting by running gpedit.msc (on the server side) and then going to: Computer Configuration\Administrative Templates\Windows Components\Remote Desktop Services\Remote Desktop Session Host\Remote Session Environment\Limit maximum display resolution

[image]